# VHDL: Using multiple If statement instead of for Loop in VHDL

Tags: vhdl

The following code contains a vhdl file and a test bench for it.

```
Main file

library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity lici is
port(PT_MSB : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
PT_LSB: in std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
--key: in std_logic_vector(127 downto 0);
RK1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
RK2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
clk: in std_logic;
CT_LSB: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
CT_MSB: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
check: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
end lici;

architecture beh of lici is
type S_BOX is array(15 downto 0)of std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
signal sub: S_BOX:=(0=>x"3",1=>x"F",2=>x"E",3=>x"1",4=>x"0",5=>x"A",6=>x"5",7=>x"8",8=>x"c",9=>x"4",10=>x"B",11=>x"2",12=>x"9",13=>x"7",14=>x"6",15=>x"D");
begin
 process(clk)
   Variable var_PT_MSB : std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   variable var_PT_LSB : std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
   variable var_EN_PT_MSB: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   variable var_XOR_RK_SHR7: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   variable var_XOR_SHL3: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   variable var_CT_LSB: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
   variable S_data: std_logic_vector(3 downto 0);
   variable outside_counter: natural:= 0;
   variable i: natural:= 1; 
   begin
var_PT_MSB:= PT_MSB;
var_PT_LSB:= PT_LSB;

if(outside_counter< 31) then

if(clk'event and clk='1' and i <= 8) then

  S_data:= (var_PT_MSB(31 downto 28) and x"F"); 

  case S_data is
   when x"0"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(0);
   when x"1"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(1);
   when x"2"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(2);
   when x"3"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(3);
   when x"4"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(4);
   when x"5"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(5);
   when x"6"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(6);
   when x"7"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(7);
   when x"8"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(8);
   when x"9"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(9);
   when x"A"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(10);
   when x"B"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(11);
   when x"C"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(12);
   when x"D"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(13);
   when x"E"=> var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(14);
   when others=>var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(15);
  end case;

   var_PT_MSB:= std_logic_vector(shift_left(unsigned(var_PT_MSB),4));
 i:=i+1;
 end if;

   var_XOR_SHL3:= var_EN_PT_MSB xor RK1 xor var_PT_LSB;
   var_XOR_SHL3:= std_logic_vector(rotate_left(unsigned(var_XOR_SHL3),3));
   var_XOR_RK_SHR7:= var_EN_PT_MSB xor RK2 xor var_XOR_SHL3;
   CT_LSB<= std_logic_vector(rotate_right(unsigned(var_XOR_RK_SHR7),7));
   var_CT_LSB:= std_logic_vector(rotate_right(unsigned(var_XOR_RK_SHR7),7));
   CT_MSB<= var_XOR_SHL3;

var_PT_MSB:= var_XOR_SHL3;
var_PT_LSB:= var_CT_LSB;
check<= var_EN_PT_MSB;
outside_counter:= outside_counter+1;
end if;
end process;
end beh; 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
This is the test bench for it


library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;
use ieee.numeric_std.all;

entity lici_tb is
end lici_tb;

architecture behav of lici_tb is
 component lici is
  port(PT_MSB : in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  PT_LSB: in std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0);
  RK1: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  RK2: in std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
  clk: in std_logic;
  CT_LSB: out std_logic_vector (31 downto 0);
  CT_MSB: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
check: out std_logic_vector(31 downto 0)
);
 end component;

signal clk :std_logic := '0';
signal PT_MSB:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):=x"ABCDEF01";
signal PT_LSB:std_logic_vector( 31 downto 0):=x"23456789";
signal RK1:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):=x"00000010";
signal RK2:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0):= x"00000001";
signal CT_LSB:std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal CT_MSB: std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);
signal check:  std_logic_vector(31 downto 0);

constant CLK_PERIOD : time := 10 ns;

begin
 uut : lici port map (
            PT_MSB => PT_MSB,
    PT_LSB=>PT_LSB,
    RK1=>RK1,
    RK2=> RK2,
        clk => clk, 
    CT_LSB=>CT_LSB,
            CT_MSB => CT_MSB,
    check=>check
        );   

Clk_process :process
   begin
        clk <= '0';
        wait for CLK_PERIOD/2;  --for half of clock period clk stays at '0'.
        clk <= '1';
        wait for CLK_PERIOD/2;  --for next half of clock period clk stays at '1'.
   end process;
end;
```

---

At the end I need to have 31 values in CT_LSB and CT_MSB.
In each cycle I wish to have different encrypted values in CT_LSB and CT_MSB,
In one cycle one iteration of outside_counter  needs to happen in which  8 NIBBLE has to encrypted.
 This entire code needs to work without using a For Loops.
Can someone help me with this?

Comment: `needs to work without using a For Loops` Why?

Comment: Did you know that if you don't declare `S_DATA` the wong type, that whole huge ugly `CASE` statement simplifies to `var_EN_PT_MSB(35-(i*4) downto 32-(i*4)):=sub(S_DATA);` ? As to your actual question, I can't see the FOR loop you are trying to replace, so I can't help with that.